# How to combine 4 grayscale images in to single grayscale image using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have divided a grayscale image into four parts, now when i am trying to combine them i am getting index outbound errors, below is the code i wrote trying to combine the images in to single gray scale image , can someone look into it and give me an answer.

```
img=Image.open("Eye retina.jpg")
im=np.asarray(img)
m,n = img.size
es=im.copy()

#Dividing image into 4 parts

Am,An=m//2,n//2
es1=es[:An,:Am]
es2=es[An:,:Am]
es3=es[:An,Am:]
es4=es[An:,Am:]

#Combine 4 images to one

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if(i<An and j<Am):
            base[i,j]=es211[An,Am]
        if(i>=An and j<Am):
            base[i,j]=es212[i,j]
        if(i<An and j>=Am):
            base[i,j]=es221[i,j]
        if(i>=An and j>=Am):
            base[i,j]=es222[i,j]
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't define `base`, it can't possibly work. (Also, `es211`, etc. are undefined.)

Comment: If you don't especially need to play with Numpy arrays, you could just use `img.paste()`.

Comment: You can use [np.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack) and [np.hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) or [np.block](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block) to combine the arrays. And similarly [np.hsplit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html) and [np.vsplit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html) to split them up.